# Django definicion parametro data

Tags: python, django

Hola buenas estoy aprendiendo Django, mas enfocado en el tema de las APIS REST con Rest_framework, el caso es que en las vistas basadas en clases y en las funciones hay un parametro que se repite mucho y es **data**.

El problema es que **data** aparece de formas mas o menos distintas y siempre lleva a confusión

¿Cual es la definición exacta de **data** dentro de Django?

Algunos ejemplos :

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def signup(self, request):
        serializer = UserSignUpSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.save()
        data = UserModelSerializers(user).data
        return Response(data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREAT
```

Por ejemplo aqui , **request** si entiendo por que se llama, pero no entiendo por que se llama a **data**

Answer (score 0):

La `data` consiste a todos los datos que llegan o envías en una api.

Cuando tu creas una api y envías información al front todo lo que lleva adentro es la `data`

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "last_login": "2020-11-05T14:56:00Z",
    "nombre": "dreika",
    "ap_paterno": "lina",
    "email": "dreika@hotmail.com",
    "genero": 1,
    "activo": true
  }
]
```

Cada vez que modificas algo en tu vista que tiene que ver sobre la data indicas que quieres obtener o mandar información.